# I cant store html inputs at javascript to use

Tags: javascript, html, css, factorial

I am trying to do a website to get the factorialize of the number that I writed at the input

```js
//setting up variables
let getnumber = document.querySelector("#get-Number");
let gotvalue = getnumber.value;
let getbutton = document.querySelector("#get-button");
let result = document.querySelector("#result-number");
let lastResult = 0;

//My Functions       
function factorialize(num) {
  if (num === 0 || num === 1)
    lastResult = 1;
  else if (num < 0) {
    lastResult = 0;
  }
  for (var i = num - 1; i >= 1; i--) {
    num *= i;
  }
  lastResult = num;
}

function write() {
  factorialize(getnumber.value)
  getbutton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    result.innerText = lastResult;
  })
}
write() //calling write
```

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(75, 4, 75);
  color: wheat;
}

.container {
  /*background-color:black;*/
  display: flexbox;
}

h1 {
  margin-left: 42%;
  margin-top: 200px;
}

#get-Number {
  margin-left: 35%;
  border-top-left-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 350px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  background-color: rgba(128, 0, 128, 0.164);
  color: wheat;
}

#get-button {
  border-top-right-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
  height: 55px;
  width: 150px;
  border: none;
  background-color: rgba(128, 0, 128, 0.164);
  color: wheat;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
}

#result-container {
  margin-left: 50%;
  height: 35px;
}

#result-number {
  padding-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Factorialize A Number</h1>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <form>
    <input type="number" placeholder="Write your number" id="get-Number">
    <button type="button" id="get-button">Get Number</button>
  </form>
</div>

<div class="container" id="result-container">
  <h4>Result</h4>
  <div id="result-number">0</div>
</div>
```

I am new at this coding era and I don't have any friends to help me I hope someone could help me at this platform.In this code I am tried to have the value of the input element then I wanted to push it in the factorialize function to get its factorialized version to push it to the result.innertext to show it in the web page.

When I try console.log to control them it shows nothing because theres nothing that user put in the input when ı try to put it before running the code it just refreshes the page.

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there, but you never update `lastResult`, which is also unnecessary here.

Instead of using that, just use the current value of the input *at the time* the button is clicked and pass it to `factorialize`. For that to work, factorialize needs to explicitly `return` what it has calculcated:

```js
let getnumber = document.querySelector("#get-Number");
let getbutton = document.querySelector("#get-button");
let result = document.querySelector("#result-number");

function factorialize(num) {
  for (var i = num - 1; i >= 1; i--) {
    num *= i;
  }
  return num;
}

getbutton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  result.textContent = factorialize(getnumber.value);
})
```

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(75, 4, 75);
  color: wheat;
}

.container {
  /*background-color:black;*/
  display: flexbox;
}

h1 {
  margin-left: 42%;
  margin-top: 200px;
}

#get-Number {
  margin-left: 35%;
  border-top-left-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 350px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  background-color: rgba(128, 0, 128, 0.164);
  color: wheat;
}

#get-button {
  border-top-right-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
  height: 55px;
  width: 150px;
  border: none;
  background-color: rgba(128, 0, 128, 0.164);
  color: wheat;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
}

#result-container {
  margin-left: 50%;
  height: 35px;
}

#result-number {
  padding-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Factorialize A Number</h1>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <form>
    <input type="number" placeholder="Write your number" id="get-Number">
    <button type="button" id="get-button">Get Number</button>
  </form>
</div>

<div class="container" id="result-container">
  <h4>Result</h4>
  <div id="result-number">0</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Only Problem I found is that you do not call factorialize function also in click event listener function because this reason your lastResult variable is not updated and the answer is showing empty.

Check below code.

```js
//setting up variables
let getnumber = document.querySelector("#get-Number");
let gotvalue = getnumber.value;
let getbutton = document.querySelector("#get-button");
let result = document.querySelector("#result-number");
let lastResult = 0;

//My Functions       
function factorialize(num) {
  if (num === 0 || num === 1)
    lastResult = 1;
  else if (num < 0) {
    lastResult = 0;
  }
  for (var i = num - 1; i >= 1; i--) {
    num *= i;
  }
  lastResult = num;
}

function write() {
  factorialize(getnumber.value)
  getbutton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    factorialize(getnumber.value) // call factorialize function also in click event listener function
    result.innerText = lastResult;
  })
}
write() //calling write
```

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(75, 4, 75);
  color: wheat;
}

.container {
  /*background-color:black;*/
  display: flexbox;
}

h1 {
  margin-left: 42%;
  margin-top: 200px;
}

#get-Number {
  margin-left: 35%;
  border-top-left-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 350px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  background-color: rgba(128, 0, 128, 0.164);
  color: wheat;
}

#get-button {
  border-top-right-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
  height: 55px;
  width: 150px;
  border: none;
  background-color: rgba(128, 0, 128, 0.164);
  color: wheat;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
}

#result-container {
  margin-left: 50%;
  height: 35px;
}

#result-number {
  padding-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Factorialize A Number</h1>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <form>
    <input type="number" placeholder="Write your number" id="get-Number">
    <button type="button" id="get-button">Get Number</button>
  </form>
</div>

<div class="container" id="result-container">
  <h4>Result</h4>
  <div id="result-number">0</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man! Is lastResult unnecessary at this code ?

Comment: Yes, Sir lastResult variable is unnecessary. You can simply return the result from factorialize function and store in variable and show the result.

Comment: @AliMelihKöksal If you say to remove lastResult variable from my answer. I will edit my answer and remove lastResult variable and make it work without lastResult variable.